# System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform on Azure DevOps self hosted agent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I'm running UI tests on my self hosted agent, when trying to restore the database I get the following error message:

> [ERROR] System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

These are my Dependencies

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Appium.WebDriver" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform" Version="14.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin" Version="3.9.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecRun.SpecFlow" Version="3.9.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="5.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My buildpipline is working fine and looks like that:
[image]

And when running `dotnet --info` on the agent machine I get the following output

```
 Version:   2.1.524
 Commit:    ab11250770

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.524\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.28
  Commit:  612cb8b183

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.524 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

any Ideas?

Edit:
In my Release Pipeline which runs my program I needed to add the `Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.816` task.

[image]

but now I get a different error:

> [ERROR] The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. -> The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. -> Unable to load DLL 'sni.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Comment: Have you tried switching to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: @mason now it says `[ERROR] Strings.PlatformNotSupported_DataSqlClient`

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using .NET Core 2.x but your SDK version greater than 2.x or lower, then go ahead and upgrade it to similar according to your .net core version. for example- 2.1.2/2.3.2/2.3.1/2.2.1 etc.

so your `System.Data.SqlClient` version should follow this rule. you can upgrade this version according to the rules.

I think it's will resolve your issue.

**UPDATE**

Add this to your `function .csproj file’s <PropertyGroup>`

```
<SkipFunctionsDepsCopy>true</SkipFunctionsDepsCopy>
```

[image]

Comment: 2.1.28 is the latest available version vor .net core
and for the sdk I am not able to select 2.1.28

Comment: @0brine please clarify that. why you not able to upgrade your SDK.

Comment: You are already installed ```Version="4.8.2"``` I found this from your dependencies code. so upgrade this by installing the lower version because I think you are using .net core version 2.1.0.

Comment: My target framework is .NET 2.1 and the Pipline uses 2.1.816 because its the latest 2.1.*, and i cant use 2.1.28 for the sdk because it this version does not exist. Should I downgrade System.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: I downgraded System.Data.SqlClient to version 2.0.0 still the same error

Comment: sadly no changes nothing has changed

Comment: @0brine clean and rebuild your solution. let me know what's happened then.

Comment: also, upgrade latest version ```System.Data.SqlClient```

Comment: Error still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234859/discussion-between-0brine-and-pritom-sarkar).